# Android SDK sdkmanager progress update

Tags: android, command-line, android-sdk-tools

A recent version of the Android SDK replaced the legacy Java "SDK Manager" GUI tool (started by the `android` command) with a new `sdkmanager` command line tool. Updates to the local Android SDK can now be performed by running `sdkmanager --update`.

When running `sdkmanager --update` it just seems to "hang" and eventually comes back with `done`. Is there a way to output status information during the update, i.e. number of pending updates/total download size/ongoing data transfer/etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest SDK tools (`26.1.1` as of Sept 27th, 2017), we now have a download progress bar:

```
$ sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.2"
[=====================                  ] 50% Downloading build-tools_r26.0.2-ma
```

It seems there is no option to show this progress when using older versions. Solution: Update SDK tools.

Answer (score 0):

apparently there is no sure way to monitor the progress of the installation or update of a package (unless you monitor your network traffic), as for me i just open the folder where the package is going and see the progress from there as files and folders appear. the objective in this case is that you want the android platform added or package. I wouldn't worry about how it downloads so long as a flag is raised when the process is done and the platform works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sdkmanger "package" --verbose
```